# How to get date from datetime in crystal report?

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, type-conversion, syntax-error

I have the datetime format in my sqldatabase was "2012-07-21 00:00:00.000". I need the date(21) only. Am trying to convert but it was showing database error for this particular field.

My Code is:
**DatePart('d',CDate({tblFiles.Filed_Date}));**

[image: My error Page]

Comment: Have you tried `DatePart('d',{tblFiles.Filed_Date})` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the connection of your report to the database. Make sure to set the data source correctly. You may start by verifying the report.

Comment: are you using seagate? what version?

Comment: using crystal report (version 13.0) with visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

Okay I had this problem in the past, which is dealt with some bits of conversions, here is an example to how I dealt with this issue, here I did not have date but I had time in my database, you need to convert it to text and replace the number of zeros you see and display x as Date(x); and then right click the field and format it to just get the data, by right clicking it. hope this helps.

```
LOCAL STRINGVAR x := REPLACE(totext({DETAILED_FOR_EMPLOYEE.LOGIN_TIME}), '.0000000', '')
```